# Summing two dictionaries read from pickled/unpickled files

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, pickle

I have two dictionaries with the same structure but different values.
I generate them with some other code and then save to file by using pickle.
Each dictionary looks like this:

```
old_damage=

{"['1000']": {'13': '1.00E+00', '5': '1.00E+00', ...,
 "['1001']": {'13': '1.00E+00', '5': '1.00E+00', ...}
```

My intent is to un-pickle them and sum the values key by key. For instance, if I want to sum the dictionary above to itself, I would like to get a result like:

```
accumulated_damage=
    {"['1000']": {'13': '2.00E+00', '5': '2.00E+00', ...,
     "['1001']": {'13': '2.00E+00', '5': '2.00E+00', ...}
```

I have made the following attempt:

```
accumulated_damage = {}
accumulated_damage.update(old_damage)
accumulated_damage.update(current_damage)

for i in old_damage.keys():
    for j in old_damage[i].keys():
        try:
            addition = float(current_damage[i][j])+float(old_damage[i][j])
            accumulated_damage[i][j]=addition
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Unfortunately this gives correct results for the first dictionary key ['1000'], but results are incorrect for the subsequent keys. (the current_damage dictionary gets overwritten and this affects the sum and I get, for example, a value of 3 instead of 2 for dictionary key ['1001'])

How could I solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little test with a small dictionaries and it should work for your case

```
d1 = {
    "1000":
        {13:1,
        5:1},
    "1001":
        {14:2,
        5:2}
}

d2 = {
    "1000":
        {13:-1,
        5:-1},
    "1001":
        {14:-2,
        5:-2}
}

d3 = d1.copy()

for k in d1.keys():
    for x in d1[k]:
        d3[k][x] = d1[k][x]+d2[k][x]
```

Result:

```
d3
{'1000': {5: 0, 13: 0}, '1001': {5: 0, 14: 0}}
```

As you can see, the values are sumed and the result for each case is zero

Comment: if my answer was useful, can you mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

From each `key, value` pair you need to get the sum of values of the `value` variable. Then update the value based on the key.

```py
old_damage = {"['1000']": {'13': '1.00E+00',
                           '5': '1.00E+00'},
              "['1001']": {'13': '1.00E+00',
                           '5': '1.00E+00'}}

for key, val in old_damage.items():
    sum_val = sum(float(v) for v in val.values())
    for k in val.keys():
        old_damage[key][k] = str(sum_val)

print("Updated: {}".format(old_damage))
```

Result:

```py
Updated: {"['1000']": {'13': '2.0', '5': '2.0'}, "['1001']": {'13': '2.0', '5': '2.0'}}
```